# Unable to Create a Database in Blackberry eclipse

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to create a database in blackberry eclipse with jde plugins. I am using Eclipse IDE v.3.4 and pluging v. 1.1 . I have also downloaded an SqLite demo project to understand it. I have searched many sites and tried to run a sample program by copying the code, but it doesn't work. It shows a problem with the following lines:

```
import net.rim.device.api.database.*;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Database;
import net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseException;
import net.rim.device.api.database.DataTypeException;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Row;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Statement;
```

I am not getting the following things:
1) Do I have to make the net.rim.device.api.database package myself?
2) How do I create, update and retrieve information at runtime?

Comment: @ MICHAEL B.  >>>>
well i belive you mean Blackberry JDE V.5....
But i am using Eclipse as IDE and with JDE plugin...
i am USING ECLIPSE 3.4 and Its JDE plugin which is version 1.1
Cant a databse be made on it...

Comment: What BlackBerry OS are you targeting?  Sqlite is supported in BlackBerry OS 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it, I'm not sure that you are building your application with the BB JRE.

How did you create your project in Eclipse?

In your package view, there will be a line that shows something either like Blackberry JRE 5.0.0 or Blackberry JRE 4.5.0 or possibly JDK 6

In order to access your rims, you need to have the BB JRE 5.0 (or 6.0 since it came out yesterday) in your project's build path.

Comment: hi taylonr..
thanks for replyng....
I sought out the problem by updating my JDE plugin...